# Best practice for packaging Angular projects that use old Javascript reference

Tags: javascript, angular, function, variables

I'm building a Web app in Angular that needs to make calls to functions from an existing project written in pure Javascript. The original Javascript code will be used as more of a library, as it contains astronomical data that is too large to rewrite in its entirety. I have my project set up with components within an app root within the src file. I'm looking to call and define variables using functions from the original javascript, but I have no idea where to begin.

[ORIGINAL JAVASCRIPT](https://github.com/mivion/ephemeris)

[MY PROJECT SETUP](https://github.com/vrnico/JSAstroCult)

Comment: nothing cosmic here [hehehe], simply include your original JS in standard script tags before the closing body tag and call your functions from anywhere within your Angular app. After a brief review of your original code, you should have no trouble accessing your global namespaces. The best practice would be to access these external features inside services. Then access the calculated values through those services. If you run into performance problems, you are perfectly set to use WebWorkers.

Comment: Damn Randy Casburn thanks for the speedy response. I’m gonna try to put some of this to use tonight and tommorow evening I’ll get back to you if I run into any issues.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I took another stab at this today, and am getting stumped on what my service should look like. How do you access specific scripts in a service, and then where are you supposed to callback the functions? It's a bummer angular hates scripts tags other wise I would just make a component that held the working aspects of the ephemeris JS in its component.html file. Either way thanks for the help Randy, Im afraid I may need to go back to the drawing board and study up on angular before I tackle this one successfully

Comment: It's quite easy actually. Since you are using AngularCLI, all you have to do is put the script file path/name reference in the `scripts` array of the angular-cli.json file. When your app is built, those script files (and css files in the styles array) are placed into script tags automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks @RandyCasburn I ended up getting it to work through npm installing the package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ephemeris-moshier), and running `var ephemeris = require('ephemeris-moshier');` in my directives on the specific components it uses.

Comment: that is the better option for sure. I didn't realize there was an NPM package or I would have advised this soluiton! Awesome.

Comment: Hey, can I get some cred for working with you? I'll put up an answer and you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Two posible solutions with AngularCLI:

1) put the script file path/name reference in the scripts array of the angular-cli.json file. When your app is built, those script files (and css files in the styles array) are placed into script tags automatically for you. It is then available globally.

2) if there is an NPM package available for the third party solution, then `npm install packagename --save` then `require()` or `import` that module where you need it in Angular.